# Match-Index or Copy cell value to a specifically named range

Tags: vba, excel

Background: I have a calculation program that gives me temperature values of nodes at different times (time step is 30 sec and up to 120 min, number of nodes can vary up to 200'000). The program gives me node numbers and corresponding temperature values in columns (see picture) and I have to export/paste/transfer these temperature values to another worksheet where I have the nodes according to their placement in the structure.

The placement of the nodes can vary and I have to run calculations at different times, so I thought about naming each node through name manager. I managed to do that and now each nodes range has a name that consist of "_" & nodes number. I named those ranges because the values will be over written many many times, but a ranges name will be a constant.

The problem: I cant seem to find a way to link a cell (cells value) (nodes number that I got from another program) and ranges name. What I would need is for the range to look in columns A,C,E,G,I and find the right node and then take the value of the cell in the next column (most likely through OFFSET).

I am thankful for any helpful information on how to proceed. I tried to find a solution to the problem and failed, but if you can reference to any existing material on how to deal with the issue at hand I would be forever grateful.

[Number of the node in rows A,C,E,G,I and temp. of the node in rows B,D,F,H,J. Named ranges of nodes on another sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqnG4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a pattern in your raw data on how it corolates with a nodes position within your structure. Perhaps the solution lies more in line with the generation of your raw data to include node location. A few different approaches are listed below.

1. One example would be a naming convention of your node. IE
   (pos#_node#). We could then write a script to locate the pos# within
   your node's name and map it out on the second sheet.
2. Unless each column represents a different section of your structure
   and will generate different node numbers with each calculation, then
   405 could simply be linked to E4 of your raw data.
3. If neither is the case then perhaps the raw data generator can be
   re-written to include a 3rd column of data corosponding to the nodes
   location.

In any case you need to be able to look at the raw data and predictably map the location. If I am missing the pattern please let me know and I will edit my response.

Comment: The raw data comes from another program as an .txt file and I import the necessary data from that file. The raw data has no correlation to the location of the node. It is just a list of nodes and temperature in that node. As the raw data is generated by another program (not my creation) I can not change the way it presents data (to add the location of the node). I was wondering if there was a way to go through the list of nodes and find a named range that has the same name as the node?

Comment: In that case you are better off keeping a "Roster" of sorts. Another sheet or workbook that will contain location data with the node name. Then you could index the location to pull the node and write your code to map it.